# "umount failed: Invalid argument." when trying to umount overlapping mounts

Tags: mount, partition, lvm, unmounting

I have a shared RHEL 8.8 system that was misconfigured such that multiple partitions have been mounted at the same mount point `/home` - a local LVM partition and a network share mounted using autofs:

```
[root@lind4573 ~]# mount | grep /home
/dev/mapper/rhel-home on /home type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,noquota)
auto_home on /home type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=6,pgrp=1839,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,indirect,pipe_ino=41411)
```

The local partition is a mistake - the network drive is what folks actually use for their home directories.  I want to unmount the local partition so that I can delete it and reallocate the space to a different partition.  However, when I try to unmount the partition by device name, I get an `Invalid argument` error.  I also tried umounting by the LVM device name and by mount point and filesystem type, but those didn't work either.

```
[root@lind4573 ~]# umount /dev/mapper/rhel-home
umount: /dev/mapper/rhel-home: umount failed: Invalid argument.
[root@lind4573 ~]# umount -A /dev/mapper/rhel-home
umount: ???: operation failed: Invalid argument.
[root@lind4573 ~]# umount /dev/rhel/home
umount: /dev/rhel/home: umount failed: Invalid argument.
[root@lind4573 ~]# umount -t xfs /home
umount: /home: target is busy.
```

I can't stop/unmount autofs since other users are using the system (so stopping autofs temporarily and unmounting by mount point isn't an option).  I can't delete this LVM partition until it's been unmounted.  How can I unmount `/dev/mapper/rhel-home` so that I can delete it?